# Connection to Bluetooth watch and get data from it

Tags: java, android

I have a watch supports bluetooth or some bluetooth device which gives some readings...now my question is how to connect to that bluetooth device, get those readings from it and display it in my android application.  I'm new to this please help me solving this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's required in this site that you Google and make some research; give folks sample code what you tried before you post your question. That is why some folks downvoted your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has training about how to connect Bluetooth device and how to read and write something between your Bluetooth device and your android device,see http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html for how to make it,and there is a demo you can refer:http://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html